# HP 8620 - EWS Web Interface won't load on https

Tags: networking, printer

Probably a bit of a niche issue, but I have a brand new HP 8620 multifunction inkjet printer. It's connected by network cable and has a static IP. When accessing the web interface (EWS), I can access the basics. However, some options can only be configured by https.

The printer tries to redirect me to the https page, but it will never load (different browsers give a different message, but generally, "took too long to respond").

I've tried:

- Factory reset
- Firmware upgrade
- Disable IPv6

Any suggestions before it goes back to HP?

Comment: Did you try a couple of different browsers?

Comment: Yep, different browsers (Inc. IE) on multiple machines

Comment: http://www.postseek.com/meta/f216463e88118f7e7b69a11d14a14802 "redirected to a secure (HTTPS-enabled) page. this page cannot open for me. i am running Mac OS Lion

So only way i got this to work was to use my work laptop with **windows 7 and firefox**. the redirection to the https site for HP freaks out IE, safari, and chrome"

Comment: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/ePrint-Print-Apps-Mobile-Printing-and-ePrintCenter/HP-OfficeJet-Pro-8620-Embedded-Web-Server/td-p/5001803 covers this problem

Comment: Indeed, it does cover it, but doesn't show a solution. I didn't try Firefox (everything but!), so will try that tomorrow